# Defining a field relation with an abstract model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I just surrendered after hours trying to test defining a relation with an abstract model, I tried polymorphic but no luck, I also tried GenericForeignKey .. also no luck, Here is my little code

```
class Attribute(models.Model):
    name       = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class TemplateField(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=30)
    attributes = models.ManyToManyField(Attribute, through='AttributeValue')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Domain(TemplateField):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=33)



class AttributeValue(models.Model):
    templatefield     = models.ForeignKey(TemplateField)
    attribute  = models.ForeignKey(Attribute)
    value      = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

When I tried GenericForeignKey, I was not sure what to do with my "Domain" Model and how to modify it, and as you know I am getting the error below [while makemigrate] :

```
wiki.AttributeValue.templatefield: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'TemplateField', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
wiki.AttributeValue.templatefield: (fields.E307) The field wiki.AttributeValue.templatefield was declared with a lazy reference to 'wiki.templatefield', but app 'wiki' doesn't provide model 'templatefield'.
wiki.AttributeValue: (fields.E336) The model is used as an intermediate model by 'wiki.Domain.attributes', but it does not have a foreign key to 'Domain' or 'Attribute'.
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, The easy answer is "you can't fix what you're doing" - you just can't have a foreign key field on something that isn't real (TemplateField being Abstract means its not going to get generated).

I think the question is, does TemplateField *have* to be abstract. Django deals with inheritance for models quite nicely, it does mean you have the extra Db table, but it would work 'fine'.

You might consider adding more functionality to TemplateField for you to know 'what kind of Template field' i.e. if you try to load the Templatefield '3', it knows its a domain and returns it - it all depends if you intend to allow an instance ot have multiple types inheritance of Template.